# How to access the items with square braces using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can't access some items in nested collection.

The array:

```
$scope.myArray = {
    "pm_id": 2,
    "type": "Scrum",
    "estimated_end_date": "Wednesday, March 15, 2017",
    "no_of_sprints": 2,
    "status": "Not Started",
    "created_by": "admin@admin.com",
    "sprint": [
        {
            "s_id": 4,
            "p_id": 35,
            "sprint_stage": "Sprint 1",
            "sprint_requirement_[1]": "<p>description goes here </p>",
            "sprint_start_date_[1]": "Monday, March 13, 2017",
            "sprint_end_date_[1]": "Friday, March 17, 2017"
        }, 
        {
            "s_id": 5,
            "p_id": 35,
            "sprint_stage": "Sprint 2",
            "sprint_requirement_[2]": "<p>description goes here </p>",
            "sprint_start_date_[2]": "Monday, March 20, 2017",
            "sprint_end_date_[2]": "Friday, March 24, 2017"
        }
    ]
}
```

HTML with ng-repeat:-

```
<p ng-repeat="y in myArray">
<p ng-repeat="x in myArray.sprint">{{x.p_id}} , {{x.sprint_requirement_[1]}}</p></p>
```

`{{x.p_id}}` is working fine, but the `{{x.sprint_requirement_[1]}}` is getting blank.

Can anyone let me know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<p ng-repeat="x in myArray.sprint">{{ x.p_id }}, {{ x['sprint_requirement_[' + ($index + 1) + ']'] }}</p>
```

Also, the external `ng-repeat` seems superfluous to me.

Explanation: in Javascript, you can access object properties both using the dot operator and the square bracket syntax.

Comment: `sprint[1]` doesn't contain object with property `sprint_requirement_[1]`.

Comment: `sprint[0]` does contain `sprint_requirement_[1]`... I have updated my answer to account for the numbering... (that's a really weird data structure, by the way...).

Answer (score 0):

First, your myArray isn't an array, so an ng-repeat won't work.
Second, your sprint_requirement shouldn't have an index on them.

```
$scope.myArray = [{
  "pm_id": 2,
  "type": "Scrum",
  "estimated_end_date": "Wednesday, March 15, 2017",
  "no_of_sprints": 2,
  "status": "Not Started",
  "created_by": "admin@admin.com",
  "sprint": [{
    "s_id": 4,
    "p_id": 35,
    "sprint_stage": "Sprint 1",
    "sprint_requirement": "description goes here",
    "sprint_start_date": "Monday, March 13, 2017",
    "sprint_end_date": "Friday, March 17, 2017"
  }, {
    "s_id": 5,
    "p_id": 35,
    "sprint_stage": "Sprint 2",
    "sprint_requirement": "description goes here",
    "sprint_start_date": "Monday, March 20, 2017",
    "sprint_end_date": "Friday, March 24, 2017"
  }]
}];
```

Third, with your html, the first ng-repeat declares y as a variable, therefore the second ng-repeat should work on the sprint array inside that variable.
:

```
<div ng-repeat="y in myArray">
  <p class="lead">{{y.type}}</p>
  <p ng-repeat="x in y.sprint">{{x.p_id}} , {{x.sprint_requirement}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("app",[]) 
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){ 
$scope.myArray = [{ "pm_id": 2, "type": "Scrum", "estimated_end_date": "Wednesday, March 15, 2017", "no_of_sprints": 2, "status": "Not Started", "created_by": "admin@admin.com", "sprint": [{ "s_id": 4, "p_id": 35, "sprint_stage": "Sprint 1", "sprint_requirement_[1]": "<p>description goes here </p>", "sprint_start_date_[1]": "Monday, March 13, 2017", "sprint_end_date_[1]": "Friday, March 17, 2017" }, { "s_id": 5, "p_id": 35, "sprint_stage": "Sprint 2", "sprint_requirement_[2]": "<p>description goes here </p>", "sprint_start_date_[2]": "Monday, March 20, 2017", "sprint_end_date_[2]": "Friday, March 24, 2017" }]}] })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="y in myArray">
   <p ng-repeat="x in y.sprint">{{x.p_id}} , {{x['sprint_requirement_['+($index +1) +']']}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```